# How to retrieve SellableItem?

Tags: sitecore-commerce, sxa-storefront

I'm using Sitecore 9 + Ecommerce Update 1.
I have a custom SXA component which uses as data source some Commerce Product.

[image]

For displaying all data I need to retrieve an Ecommerce Sellable item. I also need all variants under parent items. 
What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just received an answer from Sitecore support.

You have to reference next dlls:

- Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.Connect
- Sitecore.Commerce.ServiceProxy
- Microsoft.OData.Client

To retrieve the sellable item from Sitecore Commerce 9 Update 1 you can use following code snippet. 
To retrieve a sellable item **without** variants:

`var container = Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.Connect.EngineConnectUtility.GetShopsContainer();
var sellableItem = Sitecore.Commerce.ServiceProxy.Proxy
.GetValue<SellableItem>(container.SellableItems
.ByKey("Habitat_Master,Entity-SellableItem-6042134,")
.Expand("Components"));`

or

`var sellableItem = Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.Connect.Search.IndexUtility
.GetSellableItem("Habitat_Master,Entity-SellableItem-6042134,")`

where Habitat_Master is catalog name and Entity-SellableItem-6042134 is id of the sellable item.

To retrieve a sellable item **with** variants:

`var sellableItem = Sitecore.Commerce.ServiceProxy.Proxy
.GetValue<SellableItem>(container1.SellableItems
.ByKey("Habitat_Master,Entity-SellableItem-6042134,")
.Expand("Components($expand=ChildComponents($expand=ChildComponents($expand=ChildComponents($expand=ChildComponents))))"));`

Answer (score 0):

To achive this you can use commerce connect with the ICatalogrepository from the namespace sitecore.commerce.connect.commerceserver.catalog .

There is a getproduct() which can so what you need.

With the ProductFamily which is retrieved you get all Information about Product and variants.

Comment: Hello @Christian. Thank you for the answer, but I can't find mentioned namespace. In which assembly it locates?

Comment: It is in theq sitecore.commerceserver.connect. can be found as nuget package in the commerce feed

Comment: Is it compatible with Sitecore 9 + Ecommerce Update 1?

Comment: This I dont know. I have it in use with Sitecore Commerce 8.2.1.

Answer (score 0):

For 9.0.2
This I dont know. I have it in use with Sitecore Commerce 8.2.1. But for your answer I just reflectored a bit inside the 9.0.2 dll and found some implementation of en eqivalent implementation

`public override Item GetProduct(string productId, string catalogName)
    {
      Assert.ArgumentNotNullOrEmpty(catalogName, nameof (catalogName));
      Item obj = (Item) null;
      ISearchIndex index = CommerceTypeLoader.CreateInstance<ICommerceSearchManager>().GetIndex(catalogName);
      string catalogId = this.StorefrontContext.CurrentStorefront.CatalogItem.ID.ToGuid().ToString();
      int num = 0;
      using (IProviderSearchContext searchContext = index.CreateSearchContext((SearchSecurityOptions) num))
      {
        ParameterExpression parameterExpression;
        // ISSUE: method reference
        // ISSUE: method reference
        CommerceSellableItemSearchResultItem searchResultItem = searchContext.GetQueryable<CommerceSellableItemSearchResultItem>().Where<CommerceSellableItemSearchResultItem>((Expression<Func<CommerceSellableItemSearchResultItem, bool>>) (item => item.CommerceSearchItemType == "SellableItem")).Where<CommerceSellableItemSearchResultItem>((Expression<Func<CommerceSellableItemSearchResultItem, bool>>) (item => item.Language == this.Context.Language.Name)).Where<CommerceSellableItemSearchResultItem>((Expression<Func<CommerceSellableItemSearchResultItem, bool>>) (item => item.Name == productId.ToLowerInvariant())).Where<CommerceSellableItemSearchResultItem>((Expression<Func<CommerceSellableItemSearchResultItem, bool>>) (item => item.ParentCatalogList.Contains<string>(catalogId))).Where<CommerceSellableItemSearchResultItem>((Expression<Func<CommerceSellableItemSearchResultItem, bool>>) (item => item["_latestversion"].Equals("1"))).Select<CommerceSellableItemSearchResultItem, CommerceSellableItemSearchResultItem>(Expression.Lambda<Func<CommerceSellableItemSearchResultItem, CommerceSellableItemSearchResultItem>>((Expression) Expression.MemberInit(Expression.New(typeof (CommerceSellableItemSearchResultItem)), (MemberBinding) Expression.Bind((MethodInfo) MethodBase.GetMethodFromHandle(__methodref (SearchResultItem.set_ItemId)), )))); //unable to render the statement
        if (searchResultItem != null)
          obj = searchResultItem.GetItem();
      }
      return obj;
    }`

[image]

This can be found within OOTB existing SearchManager.cs from namespace Sitecore.Commerce.XA.Foundation.CommerceEngine.Managers 
Maybe this could help you

Comment: Hello Christian. Thank you for an answer. But this is not exactly what I need.
I opened Sitecore support ticket and I'll update this topic when they give me an answer.